# How to have a script tag work ONLY on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, script-element

I wrote a JavaScript file which is only necessary for users with Firefox so I don't want other users to even load it.

```
<script src="js/myfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is it possible to modify this tag so it only works on Firefox?

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the browser name, you can use:

```
navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
```

And for loading the another script, you can use the jquery way:

```
$.getScript("another_script.js");
```

Here a snippet with an example (tested with firefox and chrome).

**another_script.js**

```
$(function() {
    alert("loaded");
});
```

**main.html**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <script>
            var bwsr = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
            console.log(bwsr);

            $(function() {
                if (bwsr.startsWith("mozilla")) {
                    console.log("firefox");
                    $.getScript("another_script.js");
                } else {
                    console.log("not firefox, nothing will be done here");
                }
            });

            /*
            */
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thats okay but I mean in the meta tag itself, something like `<script src="js/myfile.js" type="text/javascript" browser="firefox"></script>`